# Money converter

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, converters

it's my first post here , started programming 2 weeks ago , I can't figure out , why is the scanner "from" and "to" not connecting the answer with one of the doubles, it seems to be trying to just convert it into a number, I'm confused. Any help is appreciated :)!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            double BGN = 1;
            double USD = 1.79549;
            double EUR = 1.95583;
            double GBP = 2.53405;
            double money = Double.parseDouble((in.nextLine()));
            double from;
            from = Double.parseDouble((in.nextLine()));
            double to;
            to = Double.parseDouble((in.nextLine()));
            if (from == BGN && to == USD) {
                System.out.println((money * BGN) / USD + " USD");}
            else if (from == BGN && to == EUR){
                System.out.println((money * BGN) / EUR + " EUR");}
            else if (from == BGN && to == GBP){
                System.out.println((money * BGN) / GBP + " GBP");}
            else if (from == USD && to == BGN){
                System.out.println((money * USD) / BGN + " BGN");}
            else if (from == USD && to == EUR){
                System.out.println((money * USD) / EUR + " EUR");}
            else if (from == USD && to == GBP){
                System.out.println((money * USD) / GBP + " GBP");}
            else if (from == EUR && to == BGN){
                System.out.println((money * EUR) / BGN + " BGN");}
            else if (from == EUR && to == USD){
                System.out.println((money * EUR) / USD + " USD");}
            else if (from == EUR && to == GBP){
                System.out.println((money * EUR) / GBP + " GBP");}
            else if (from == GBP && to == BGN){
                System.out.println((money * GBP) / BGN + " BGN");}
            else if (from == GBP && to == USD){
                System.out.println((money * GBP) / USD + " USD");}
            else if (from == GBP && to == EUR){
                System.out.println((money * GBP) / EUR + " EUR");}
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Answer");}
        }
            }
```

Comment: are you aware of how bad is this? ***from == USD***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I doubt he is. Programmers doing it for years are still not aware of that.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ nop

Comment: @ Michael Markidis i need it for an exercise , why is it bad ?

Comment: you should use 'equals' instead of '==' to compare for equality. '==' checks objects identity (same objects, same address in memory) whereas equals checks for objects equivalence.